# Spacing and font in \frac

Tags: math-mode

When I write text in frac, it looks bad no space... bad font. How can I change it

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$ \frac{Lorem Ipsum}{abc dfe}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In math mode, letters are spaced like a product of variables. Ifyou really want text, load  `amsmath` and use `frac{\text{Lorem Ipsum}}{\text{abc def}}`.

Comment: it is unrelated to `\frac` spaces are ignored in math mode try `$abc def$`

Answer (score 1):

You could make the space character active in math mode to insert a thick muskip in its place.  For this you will have to modify the definition of `\obeyspaces` (which I should probably propose to the LaTeX core) to make the expansion of the obeyed space overrideable.  Then you just have to append `\obeyspaces` to `\everymath` and `\everydisplay` and you are all set to produce the most horrible-looking documents.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\obeyedspace{\space}
\def\@obeyedspace{\obeyedspace}
{\obeyspaces\global\let \@obeyedspace}
\makeatother

\renewcommand\obeyedspace{\;}
\everydisplay={\obeyspaces}
\everymath={\obeyspaces}

\begin{document}

$\frac{Lorem Ipsum}{abc dfe}$

\end{document}
```

[image]